# Вопрос по static

Tags: java, ооп

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему вот такой код компилируется

```
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new KissMyShinyMetalAss());
    }

    public static class KissMyShinyMetalAss{
    }
}
```

А вот этот не компилируется

```
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new KissMyShinyMetalAss());
    }

    public class KissMyShinyMetalAss{
    }
}
```

В одном случае внутренний класс объявлен как `static` в другом нет. Просто не могу понять как в данном случае это влияет на компиляцию и почему не позволяет создать `new KissMyShinyMetalAss`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не-static nested class подразумевает работу внутри экземпляра другого (внешнего) класса и при создании получает экземпляр этого класса через конструктор, что позволяет обращаться к нему через (в данном случае) `Solution.this`. Вот и вся причина - в статическом контексте nested class не может получить экземпляр внешнего класса.